# How to make script run run after month?

Tags: php

I'm creating a visitors counter for website. It needs to show visits in current month.
This is the code:

```
<?php
 if(file_exists('visitors.txt'))
 {
    $myFile = "visitors.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
    $myFileContents = fread($fh, 21);
    fclose($fh);
    echo $myFileContents;
    $myFile2 = "visitors.txt";
    $myFileLink2 = fopen($myFile2, 'w+') or die("Can't open file.");
    $newContents = $myFileContents+1;
    fwrite($myFileLink2, $newContents);
    fclose($myFileLink2);
    echo $newContents;
 }
 else
 {
    $myFile = "visitors.txt";
    fclose($fh)
 } 
?>
```

It creates file visistors.txt and saves number of visits. Now how I can clean this file each new month and start counting from 0?

Comment: You could save yourself a lot of trouble and store the info in a database instead.

Comment: using a cronjob to trigger another script for the resetting...

Comment: Why do you want to start from 0 each month? Why not keep the data and append a new month on the line below, or create a new file `Visitors 2018-06` or something?

Comment: cronjob is not needed.

Comment: Btw, do you really want `or die("Can't open file.")` in that script? Should you completely stop executing the request just because you can't store the visitor in your text file?

Comment: Andreas please write your comments as Answear. and I mark it as Answear.

Comment: Another "Btw", if the file wouldn't exist (for what ever reason) and you hit the "else" part of your code, it would fail. In that block, `$fh` is undefined and can there for not me closed.

Comment: Oh, I didnt saw it. it should say $myfile

Comment: `$myFile` isn't a file handler in the else-block, though. It's just a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the basic idea.
I see if the file exists.
If yes, then i read the contents and add one to the count and save it to the file (overwriting the previous data).
If no, create the file with count 1.

```
$ym = date("Y-m");  // 2018-05
if(file_exists('visitors-' $ym . '.txt')){ // visitors-2018-05.txt
    $count = file_get_contents('visitors-' $ym . '.txt');
    $count++;
    file_put_contents('visitors-' $ym . '.txt', $count);
}else{
    file_put_contents('visitors-' $ym . '.txt', "1");
}
```

EDIT; this should work as long as you don't open and edit the contents yourself (accidently add a space or some other letter making $count++ fail.)
You can perhaps do `$count = (int)file_get_contents('visitors-' $ym . '.txt');` but it's not completly safe.
If you need a foolproof solutiuon I think you need to regex the contents, but that is overkill and will drain memory and cpu for no good reason.
Just stay out of the file and only open it with code and you are safe.

EDIT again: Just a tip. In a few months you will have a lot of textfiles.
Save them in a separate folder to keep it clean in webroot.

Comment: You would probably want to use the `LOCK_EX`-flag as well, since I'm assuming that there can be multiple users on the site at the same time. Probably not needed, but better safe than sorry.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Honestly I have never used LOCK_EX. What does it do?

Comment: It basically puts a file lock on the file so that it can't be changed from another process while it's opened and written to (for transaction integrity). In this case, it's probably not needed at all, though, unless the OP gets a ton of users at the exact same time. But then the OP will have bigger issues with the file-solutions so.. :-) I'm just accustomed to use it when writing to files that _might_ be changed by other processes at the same time.